# calling certain elements from an XML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Kind of new to XML but, I'm working with an XML file listed below.

is there a way I can just pull certain info from each company?

for ex. I just want the info from the industry element to be shown

```
<companies>
    <company name="1" imageurl="logo">
    <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
    <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
    <industry> Risk Services </industry>
    <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
    </company>

    <company name="2" imageurl="logo">
    <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
    <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
    <industry> Risk Services </industry>
    <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
    </company>

    <company name="3" imageurl="logo">
    <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
    <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
    <industry> Risk Services </industry>
    <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
    </company>
</companies>
```

Comment: can you explain why you selected that set of question tags?

Comment: jQuery-selectors work also with XMLDocuments:`$('company>industry',xmldocument).each(function(){/*do something*/});` . The XMLDocument may be requested via `$.ajax`

Comment: I just chose the question tags related to the info that is supposed to be given, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example like this:

```
var xmlText = $('#xmlData').text();
var $xmlData = $.parseXML(xmlText)

$('company', $xmlData).each(function(index, company) {
    console.log($('industry', company).text())
});
```

see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/fcjp3rpq/) for detailed example

**UPDATE**

print results to table:

```
var xmlText = $('#xmlData').text();
var $xmlData = $.parseXML(xmlText)

$('company', $xmlData).each(function(index, company) {
    $('#companies').append(
        $(document.createElement('tr'))
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('td'))
                    .text($(this).attr('name'))
            )
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('td'))
                    .text($('industry', this).text())
            )
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('td'))
                    .text($('employee', this).text())
            )
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('td'))
                    .text($('certification', this).text())
            )
    );

    console.log($('industry', company).text())
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/fcjp3rpq/2/)

Comment: Thank you Alex, instead of it being viewed in the console. Is there a way to have it print so the user can see. For example the user clicks a button then the info will be printed in a div or table.

Comment: Thank you Alex, exactly what I was looking for. wasn't able to vote you up but thank you again